# Is there any cross-platform threading library in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, cross-platform

I'm looking for some easy to use cross-platform threading library written in C++.

What's your opinion on `boost::thread` or `Pthreads`? 
Does Pthreads run only on POSIX compliant systems?

What about the threading support in the `Qt` library?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Boost.Thread is the draft for the coming standard threading library of the C++ language. Knowing that, I prefer to use it as it provide some strong guarantees (because it becomes standard).

Update: Now that we have the standard threading libraries, some more precisions. Some boost constructs, like  boost::shared_mutex, have not been standardised (but might be later). However the standard library exploit the move semantic better. Good to know before choosing a library. Also, using C++11 threading library requires a compiler that provides it. It's not the case for all compilers today.

Update:
Now [Nov2012] most of the Standard compilers provide C++11 threading library. VS2012, GCC4.8 and Clang3.1 have support for threads and synchronization primitives and atomic operations.
For complete implementation you can also use just thread by Anthony Williams. It is C++11 compliant library supported on Windows/Mac and Linux.

Links for status of C++11 features with various compilers:

- GCC 4.8 - http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html
- Clang3.1 - http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html
- VS2012 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

Comment: I know this answer is old, but I'd like to add that gcc 4.6 won't compile Boost.Thread in C++11 mode. This might be an issue in any of them, but most likely gcc, since C++11 support is under development at the moment.

Comment: I'll add that you still have to have a compiler providing the standard threading library to use it, or otherwise rely on boost.

Answer (score 9):

There is a threading library coming with C++11. It's built upon the boost threading library. Unfortunately, I seem to remember that there are non-trivial differences between Boost.Threads and what C++11 comes with. Still, if you plan to switch to the C++ standard threading library, I believe Boost.Threads is the closest you can get to now.

I suppose that, under the hood, these libraries will use Pthreads on POSIX systems and whatever native threading support is available elsewhere.

Disclaimer: I haven't worked with either of the two.

Answer (score 4):

`Pthreads` are running only on POSIX systems. `QThread` from `Qt` is a way to go. It is available on platforms: **Linux, Mac OS X, Windows, Embedded Linux, Windows CE, Symbian, Maemo.**

Comment: What do you mean saying "All platforms"

Comment: Yeah, I have this chip here in my toaster, is Qt available for it? `:)`

Comment: Officially supported, win/mac/unix+x/embedded unix/wince/symbian/meamo - Probably more than boost.

Comment: sbi> yes if your toast provides enough memory!

Comment: @shakov: With the bread they sell here, the toast's memory is _very_ limited, but I suppose I could scratch a few digits into its surface. But then, it's lifetime really is too limited to go to the trouble. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Also have a look at [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/), it's a set of (somewhat standard) `pragma`s specifications that is supported by [most major compilers](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-compilers/). The good of OpenMP is that it's simple and that your code can be easily compiled in both single and multi-threaded versions.

Just a simple example:

```
std::vector<double> a, b;
...
double sum = 0.0;
...
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
  for (i=0; i < n; i++)
    sum = sum + (a[i] * b[i]);
```

It's obviously possible to do also [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978222/openmp-c-algorithms-for-min-max-median-average/2581498#2581498) [complex](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html) [things](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt12ch31s04.html#parallel_mode.design.tuning).

Comment: Is OpenMP supported on Windows too?

Comment: Yes, OpenMP is supported on Windows, by Visual Studio 2005 and later, and of course Intel compilers.

Comment: And it should not introduce any dependency.

Comment: But the fact is that OpenMP is designed rather for parallel task execution than just regular threading which deals with synchronization, mutexes...etc. Right?  I mean OpenMP isn't just suitable for creating a multithreaded server for example.

Comment: OpenMP definitely has synchronization primitives, but yes, I'd not use it to write a web server.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised that nobody mentioned the [Intel TBB library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118176/libstdc-parallel-mode-whos-using-it-is-it-safe-any-similar-projects/7378345#7378345) (linked to an another answer of mine). Also, a [task-based implementation should be preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543755/are-you-concerned-about-multicore/668768#668768) over a thread-based.

Comment: Yes, also the future-async model in C++11 is quite easy to go with. For Windows only PPL is very similar to TBB and is well supported by MS

Answer (score 2):

Qt has pretty good thread support. If you just need to create a thread and run some code in it, `QThread` is all you need. There are many other high-level classes that can help you with thread pools or even abstract the concurrent execution (the QtConcurrent framework).

Comment: Qt indeed has a good threading library; it works very well for Qt applications since you can connect signals across threads. If you're using Qt elements, I would stick with Qt threads.

Answer (score 2):

List the concerning platforms. If you're only using say, Linux/Mac/Windows, then boost::thread will likely do you fine until C++0x (harhar) provides std::thread.

Answer (score 2):

I have used pthreads for code that work on multiple platforms.  To get around the Windows lack of pthreads, I have used the following open source library with great success:  [POSIX Threads for Windows](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/)

Comment: pthreads-w32 is old school. mingw-w64 supplies an improved version called winpthreads.

Answer (score 1):

[wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/) has thread classes, and as wxWidgets is platform independent, it might just be the best thing for u.

Answer (score 1):

Boost.Threads is built on top of PThreads on UNIX systems and Win32 Threads on Windows.

The boost library is syntactically simple and all of the hairy business of properly interfacing C++ code with C libraries is taken care of behind the scenes.  If you're not very comfortable with C++, however, PThreads might seem more straight-forward with its simple C API.

Qt Threads is also a good library, but because I use several other boost libraries, I'll compile and link against Boost no matter what.  I might not always link against Qt.  And, well, I just don't want to remember how to use two different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

SDL is simple, cross-platform and has threading support.

Comment: SDL is rather mainly a multimedia library, isnt it? I'd rather have something more neat.

Answer (score 0):

Pthread is part of Posix, but not every posix systems will have threads. pthreads is most portable.

What platforms will you support?

Comment: Well, Pthreads has no problems running on Linux and other Unix systems I presume. But what about Pthreads on Windows?

Comment: I use pthreads on WIndows (compiled in cygwin). So there is support.