# libstdc++ parallel mode: Who's using it? Is it safe? Any similar projects?

Tags: c++, stl, parallel-processing, libstdc++

the GNU implementation of the C++ Library supports a parallel mode, explained [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html).

- Any experiences in using it? Good ones? Bad ones? Especially regarding correctness, but also performance.
- Are there some "more or less serious" projects using it?
- Do you use it with the global turn-on-parallel switch -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL or do you use it carefully with manually turn-on specific parallelization functions like: `__gnu_parallel::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`?
- Are there any similar open source projects? Meaning: more easy parallelization than using openMP.

Thanks for your experiences.

Sascha

Comment: I think you might get your answers if you ask at libstdc++@gcc.gnu.org mailing list, see http://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used it for some small projects, with a nice speedup for large stl operations. I never encountered any problems (I used the global switch). However I didn't really do much benchmarking, you might want to refer to studies like http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/singler/mcstl/parallelmode_se.pdf and http://ls11-www.cs.uni-dortmund.de/people/gutweng/AD08/VO11_parallel_mode_overview.pdf.

Answer (score 4):

Too late answer, but:

I would seriously consider Intel TBB. One thing that I noted missing from C++ standard parallel mode is parallel containers. TBB containers do not follow the interface of C++ standard containers, but they provide [justifications](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/10/13/tbb-containers-vs-stl-functionality-rift/) for this. Besides, TBB has a number of examples and design patterns.

Comment: TBB and gnu parallel mode are too different things. While you get (almost) >100 STL functions written in parallel for free, you will not get it in TBB but need code it yourself (only obvious functions like std::sort). If you know how to use STL functions this is really a good thing for parallelization. On the other hand you get some parallel containers in TBB.

Answer (score 1):

This seems similar though I haven't looked very deeply into it. http://thrust.github.com/